# Pass binary data from C to C# through the console

Tags: c#, c, image, console, binary-data

I have two applications, one written in C and the other one in C#, which talk through console string messages. They both wait until the other sends a string message.

Now I want that at a certain moment the C application sends an image in binary format through the same console I/O "channel" and that the C# application recieves it and uses it as an image to display. I know it is possible, see: [C/C++: is it possible to pass binary data through the console?](http://bit.ly/xPkRIi).

I have access to the source code of both the applications. I know where the C application-code writes the image to disk. The C# application gets the C application output by this piece of code:

```
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived); //void
p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) //e.Data.
```

How do I have to code the C and C# part of this binary image transfer? Thanks.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I would like to implement the data transfer above described in both C and C# sides, can you post some example code?

Comment: I don't have any, usually people that post here develop their own software and ask questions if they run into specific problems or questions.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I have developed my application on my own, this is the specific question I ran into. If you have no code examples please give at least some hints. It will be appreciated.

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to contains code to set the `stdin` to binary mode - and mentions you can also do this for `stdout`. You already mention how the C# application receives data. The next step would be writing to `stdout` and putting a breakpoint in C# at the `p_OutputDataReceived` handler, right?

Comment: An obvious, simple and fast solution is to use a file instead.  Not so obvious is running the C code in your C# process so you can just use memory.  You do that with pinvoke or a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: @Hans Passant My current implementation uses a file but I think it is not good, altough with good performance in fact, because it does so very often so I think it could spoil SSD drives. Are you saying that I could "emulate" an hard-disk in memory? Can you explain better?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I think the trouble is how the C# code is made aware that a string was sent. With common string I think it listens to CR/LF and then "fires" the delegate. Furthermore some translation could happen.

Comment: If you don't need to use the console, there are other IPC methods besides stdin/stdout, for instance a socket or a memory-mapped file.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is how to transfer this data, the really short answer to your question is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It was made specifically for this purpose, and has ready-made libraries for both C and C# (just look for e.g. "C# base64").

It is almost as efficient as a raw binary encoding (in terms of data transferred).

Comment: Convert.FromBase64String Method is useful by the C# side, but could you post some link to good C encoder code that doesn't need including a library preferably. Is this SO thread good? http://bit.ly/u1K2X0

Comment: Yes, it gives you some good options. Depending on the license, you could just copy the parts that deal with the encoding and not include the whole library (e.g. from glib or the GNU coreutils source).

Comment: I tried this base64 enconding but it is awfully slow. When you say it is almost as efficient as raw binary in terms of data transferred do you mean that the performance is bad instead? Or it is the console I/O channel that's slow?

Comment: I mean data transferred as in the amount of bits transferred to represent the same thing.

About the speed, it is actually what is used in email attachments, which can also be pretty big files, and it works there... But it depends on the application type. If you try to use it as an IPC channel to transfer gigabytes of information, then it's not what you want.